# Using Windows.print()..print some fields of a form.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, printing

I have a script which reads data from an external card i have two options on the page one to read data from the card and display the other is "send to printer" option here when i click on "send to printer" it should only print the required fields. The code is

```
<body>
<br>
<div align="center">
<input type="button" value="Read myKad" id="btnRead" class="btn btn-success"><img src="loading.gif" id="loading" style="display:none">  

<script language="javascript">
if (window.print) {
document.write('<input type="button" value="Sent to Printer" id="btnRead" class="btn btn-warning" onClick="window.print()">');
}
</script>
<span id="msg"></span>
</div>
<hr/>
<span id="holder"></span>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnRead").click(function(){
$("#imgpp").html("Please wait. Reading Cherry ..... ");
$("#loading").show();
$.ajax({
url: "read.php",
success: function(response){
//$("#imgpp").attr("src","http://192.168.0.4/mykadreader/sample/mypic.jpg?x=<?PHP echo date("Ymdhis"); ?>");
$("#holder").html(response);
$("#imgpp").html("Done Reading ");
$("#loading").hide()    ;   
$(".paper-table").tablecloth({
         theme: "paper",
         striped: true,
         sortable: true,
         condensed: false
       });
}
})
})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to print part of the page, only.
You can do that with a print-only css (i.e. hide the undesired things).

ie the css file would be included with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

then within this file you can set the display:none on any/all elements that aren't needed.